# Is Documentation Stack Overflow-only or does it also cover Ask Ubuntu/SU/SF/UL/other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, documentation, scope

I am asking as I see many of the [Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ubuntu/topics) topics covering system administration stuff (installation, networking setup, etc.), typically off-topic on Stack Overflow if asked about. Should such topics be allowed or rejected?

Comment: I don't think these will be on-topic for documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation is currently Stack Overflow-only and it should cover only topics that are on-topic on Stack Overflow.

In the future Documentation might be added to other Stack Exchange sites; see [Allow Documentation in other Stack Exchange communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281689/310998) [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) on Meta Stack Exchange.